# IntelliJ: Automatically update resources

Tags: angularjs, tomcat, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ IDEA to develop AngularJS app with Java back-end. HTML/JS is server from Tomcat.

Whenever I changed HTML/JS file, I hit <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> and select **Update resources**, then refresh my browser and everything is OK.

[image: IntelliJ Update Dialog]

I'd like to ask if there is a way that IntelliJ would do this **automatically** for me. I know that I can check 'Don't ask again', but sometimes I really want to Redeploy or Restart server as well ...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you go into your Server Run Configuration, on the Server tab there is an option named "On frame deactivation".  Set that to "Update resources" and then whenever IDEA loses focus, it will update the resources of the server.

Relevant docs from Intellij http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp10.5/updating-a-running-java-ee-application.html#update_on_frame_deactivation

**Edit 8/19/2020**
Thanks to Adi Gerber for providing an updated link, which is https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/updating-applications-on-application-servers.html#update (the previous one doesn't work anymore)

And here is a link to the current docs as of 8/19/2020: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/updating-applications-on-application-servers.html#update

Comment: Is there a way to do this on an external file change?

Comment: The link is broken. Here's the up-to-date one: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/updating-applications-on-application-servers.html#update

Answer (score 1):

Another **TRUE AUTOMATED APPROACH** that works very well is :

- Having an imported Maven project
- Option: **Build Tools > Maven > Importing > Import Maven Project Automatically** to keep in sync IDE compiler options specified in POM ( for example maven-compiler-plugin options)
- Plugin: **File Watcher** to watch for resources' updates
- Option: Tools > **File Watcher > Custom watches** to copy updated files via `mvn war:exploded` ( in our case Javascript and HTML )
- Option: **Build > Compiler Build Project Automatically** to update .class

In our case we deploy on **Google Cloud App Engine Devserver** which reloads files everytime they are updated

Comment: How do you copy the updated files with the file watcher?